# How to solve race conditions among K8s pods

Tags: algorithm, spring-boot, java-8, kubernetes, amazon-dynamodb

This might not have to do anything with K8s pods, but something more algorithmic I suspect. But this is the complete scenario we are facing.

Lets say we have **2 pods** -> running java application.

We have **1 Dynamo table** -> having `id`(hash_key)(not unique), `created_date`(sort_key), `id_2`

The expected behavior of the program is to check the existence of given `id` (latest) and fetch its `id_2`. If no such `id` exists then generate a new `id_2`.

Now comes the race condition -->
Two pods parallelly starts to execute the logic and both of them starts to  query the Dynamo, and coincidentally have the same `id`. Now they do not find any such `id` .. since none of them have been inserted into Dynamo and therefore they create altogether separate new `id_2`..and both pods ends up inserting new `id_2` for same `id`..  which should not be the case.

How can we solve this race condition.

Any leads will be appreciated. Thx

Comment: You could look into the suitability of transactions to coordinate inserts in a table.

Comment: To me it doesn't look like a kubernetes issue at all. You need to use transactions here to get rid off this issue. As you are using spring-boot, see how can you override transaction isolation of one particular method.

Comment: @PrateekJain But how does nosql supports transactions? Also even if transactions are managed, that would we within same pod and not across pods. Is my understanding correct? Help me understand please

Comment: nope, transactions are not at pod level. they are on DB level. I am not dynamodb expert but I can see they do support transactions https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/ . else you can introduce a column named 'version' in your table and use that to handle concurrency issues. basically, value of version should be same when you read and apply update.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoukd re-think your table schema.

By having a table with **id_2** as hash, no sort key and a global secondary index on **id**/**created_data**

Of couse this would only work if **id_2** is unique in the table, not unique for each  **id**